# BadPaddingException when decrypting with PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox, badpaddingexception

In the past, I have tried to decrypt PDFs using PDFBox using the following code:

```
if (doc.isEncrypted()){
    doc.openProtection(new StandardDecryptionMaterial(password));
    doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
}
```

(Note that I don't use `doc.decrypt(password)` because [the Javadoc for decrypt()](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.6/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#decrypt(java.lang.String)) says that [openProtection()](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.6/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#openProtection(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.DecryptionMaterial)) should be used instead, although why it's not just deprecated is beyond me).

Anyway, this has worked fine for quite a while. However, lately I seem to be getting the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
        at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:118)
        at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:236)
        at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:212)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.encryptData(SecurityHandler.java:316)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.decryptStream(SecurityHandler.java:421)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.decrypt(SecurityHandler.java:390)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.decryptObject(SecurityHandler.java:365)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.proceedDecryption(SecurityHandler.java:196)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.decryptDocument(StandardSecurityHandler.java:158)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.openProtection(PDDocument.java:1598)
            <Stack trace continues with my call to openProtection()>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2469), which appears to have been introduced as a result of a Java update. At the time of this writing, a fix for this is in review to be included in version 1.8.8, so just upgrade to version 1.8.8 or later and this problem will go away.

Comment: Yes we're working on this. Please try the 1.8.8 snapshot; if it doesn't work, please attach your file in the PDFBOX-2469 issue. https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.8-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: @Tilman I use the pdfbox-app version of the jar, but as far as I can tell, the snapshots only come in the unbundled form. Pity because I would be interested in trying it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the snapshot pdfbox-app has the same as the released version. In some cases you may need jai_imageio and/or jbig2 in your classpath.

Comment: @Tilman, Ah, I understand now. The link you gave me was for plain pdfbox, but there also exists [a repository for pdfbox-app snapshots](http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/1.8.8-SNAPSHOT/), which has what I need. I'll give it a try when I get a chance.